# Error migrating stored function to new MySQL server

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

Migrating a database from MariaDB-10.2.12 server to MySQL-5.7.28 and a stored function is giving a syntax error.

I've tried using different delimiters, no change. If I delete all the ELSEIF clauses it works, but I'm just not seeing the error in those statements.

This is the function (as obtained from mysqldump from the existing server)

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `string2int`(`input` VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8) RETURNS bigint(10)
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
DECLARE ret BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
SET input=REPLACE(input, ' ', '');
IF input REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$' THEN
  SET ret=input;
ELSEIF input REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+K' THEN
  SET ret=CAST(input AS INT)*1024;
ELSEIF input REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+M' THEN
  SET ret=CAST(input AS INT)*1024*1024;
ELSEIF input REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+G' THEN
  SET ret=CAST(input AS INT)*1024*1024*1024;
END IF;
RETURN ret;
END ;;
```

The error message:

````
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'INT)*1024; ELSEIF input REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+M' THEN SET ret=CAST(input AS INT)*' at line 10```
````

Comment: Ok I see it's in the CAST, this works on my old server but not the new one:
```
select cast('1024G' AS INT)
```

Comment: Do I just need to s/INT/UNSIGNED/ ? This seems to work in the new server:
select CAST('1024K' AS UNSIGNED)